# Routing error occurs when submitting request using .html file on my local drive instead of .erb on server

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I created a html page on my local drive (/Users/xxx/Desktop/add_student.html):

```
<form method="post" action="http://localhost:3000/students/create/">
  <input name="student[surname]"/><br/>
  <input name="student[age]"/><br/>
  <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

which will show the information of students when submit to server, server details:

config/routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :students
end
```

app/controllers/students_controller.rb:

```
class StudentsController < ApplicationController
  def create
  end

  def show
    render plain:params.as_json
  end
end
```

but when I click submit button,error occurs:

```
Routing Error
No route matches [POST] "/students/create"

Rails.root: /Users/xxx/Desktop/blog
```

but if I then click the url field on the browser and press enter, it becomes able to display the result normally:

```
{"controller"=>"students", "action"=>"show", "id"=>"create"}
```

what is the reason? how can I get the result directly after submit as if pressing enter again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Routing Error No route matches [POST] "/students/create"

`action="http://localhost:3000/students/create/"`

should be

`action="http://localhost:3000/students/"`

or just

```
action="/students/"
```

> but if I highlight the url on the browser and press enter, it can
>   display the result normally:
>
> {"controller"=>"students", "action"=>"show", "id"=>"create"}

No! That isn't write, as you can see the `action` is `show` with `id` as `create`. So it **isn't** the `create` action.

**Tip:**

Do `rake routes` and you will see `POST /students(.:format)                               students#create`. So it is just `/students` not `/students/create`

Also, make sure you have `create` method in the `students_controller` with the necessary code to create a student record.